# Get everyone who is logged into my web application restfb

Tags: java, facebook, groovy, restfb

I am currently creating an application using Java/Groovy that allows a user to login using Facebook, this works perfectly and when they successfully login I can see on the Facebook analytics who's on my web app.

Is there a way to find out all the users who are logged in to my application via the API? I am currently using restfb. I want to find all my users, check their locations and then display the ones closest to the user.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this on the Facebook developer site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the API anymore, you will have to implement that functionality on your own.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0